# Erro em programa para fazer uma lista de mercado

Tags: javascript

O problema: Ao executar no Google Chrome, o navegador acusa ter um erro na função `lerLista` embora eu não tenha conseguido resolver acredito que seja um problema a captura do campo produto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Lista de Compras</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
</head>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Item lista de compra</h2>
<form name="entradaDaLista">
  
  Produto: <input type="text" id="produtoId" name="produto" >
  Quantidade:<input type="text" id="quantidadeId" name="quantidade"  >
  Preço:<input type="text" id="precoId" name="preco" >
  <button type="button" onclick="criaLista()">Incluir</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</form>

</body>
<script>


function item(){

this.produto=document.getElementById("produtoId");
this.quantidade=document.getElementById("quantidadeId").value;
this.preco=document.getElementById("precoId").value;

}
function criaLista(){
var lista=[]; 
 for( var i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
 lista[i].push(new item());
 }
lerLista(lista);
 
}






function lerLista(lista){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +="Lista de compras <br> Produto  
Quantidade  Preço  Total";
for (var i of lista){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +="<br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" "+ lista[i].produto;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" 
"+parse.int(lista[i].quantidade);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" "+parse.int(lista[i].preco);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" 
"+parse.int(lista[i].quantidade*lista[i].preco);
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Erro retornado:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: O erro é porque tem quebra de linha no código em: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +="Lista de compras <br> Produto  
Quantidade  Preço  Total";` também em: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" 
"+parse.int(lista[i].quantidade);` e `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=" 
"+parse.int(lista[i].quantidade*lista[i].preco);`

Comment: Veja o snippet, agora da para perceber a quebra de linha no código.

Comment: Oi NoobSaibot(nome estiloso kk). Me desculpa mas poderia dizer o que é snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Sua funçao criaLista() nunca vai preencher o array lista pois a propriedade lista.length sempre é zero uma vez que você acabou de criar o array na linha de cima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Lista de Compras</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
</head>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Item lista de compra</h2>
<form name="entradaDaLista">
  
  Produto: <input type="text" id="produtoId" name="produto" >
  Quantidade:<input type="text" id="quantidadeId" name="quantidade"  >
  Preço:<input type="text" id="precoId" name="preco" >
  <button type="button" onclick="adicionaItem()">Incluir</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</form>

</body>
<script>
var lista=[]; 

function item(){

this.produto=document.getElementById("produtoId").value;
this.quantidade=document.getElementById("quantidadeId").value;
this.preco=document.getElementById("precoId").value;

}
function adicionaItem(){


 lista.push(new item());
 
  lerLista(lista);
 
}






function lerLista(lista){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML ="Lista de compras <br> Produto  Quantidade  Preço  Total";
for (var item of lista){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +="<br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += item.produto;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += item.quantidade;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += item.preco;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += parseInt(item.quantidade)*parseInt(item.preco);
}
}
</script>
</html>
```